# How to seek knowledge sharing from professional network without appearing self - serving or intrusive?

Tags: communication, networking

I am currently the team lead of the IT audit and risk team at my company. Recently business processes in IT are being [re-engineered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_reengineering) and management has approached us about assisting them to improve certain IT controls and cybersecurity incident response procedures.

While I have decent experience in IT security / risk management domain from several years of work experience and soon to be CISA, I am always open to critique and hearing of current best practices as cyber security is a very dynamic field within IT.  Many members of my professional network work in InfoSec and I am in fairly close contact with them. We do not work in the same industries and **we do not compete as rivals**.

I would like to ask them about some successful techniques  / best practices they may be using to monitor cybersecurity controls at their company, **without coming across as intrusive.** I realize this knowledge is security sensitive and may be exploitable by blackhats if misused. I also realize that from a business perspective, I am a 3rd party that should rightly raise trust issues.

> Is asking other professionals in the same industry in your network to share such knowledge appropriate in such circumstances?
>
> If yes, how can I ask for such knowledge sharing without appearing self - serving or intrusive?

Comment: you want to be self serving, yet appear that you're not?

Comment: If it's someone who you know on a vaguely personal level, just shoot them a message and ask if they'd be up for chatting about it over a drink (with you buying of course!)

Comment: Does your professional network have official LinkedIn groups, meetups, activities, etc? That appears to be the most "neutral" way to communicate. One-on-one is the most risky. Software developers do not do this in general except in broad ways eg. via Stack and other means. Even asking another non-competing company in the same co-working space what web stack they use can be extremely invasive (if deemed so by them). I can only imagine how touchy InfoSec must be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sharing knowledge is perfectly normal.**

In the majority of industries and disciplines, sharing knowledge and best practices is seen as a best practice in itself.

The main benefit is that bringing other people up to your level, allows them to find problems that may eventually affect you - and share their (now relevant) learnings back to you. In industries such as IT, Development and Security - it also increases the likelyhood of robust tools being created, as more people begin to have similar needs (again, benefitting everybody).

As evidence of this, there are a plethora of conferences, knowledge sharing events, blogs and engagement on platforms like SE - where best practices are freely exchanged. If asking for advice was always seen as self-serving, it's safe to say these avenues would not exist in such large numbers.

---

In my experience, the best way to ask for advice - is simply to ask them. Whether that's in person or via an email chain, most people will be willing to share a small amount of advice without anything more formal.

---

It is also worth being aware of the line between sharing best practices and asking for free work.

In general, if you're asking for a general pointer for things to consider/research further - you're safe (and at worst, will simply not get a reply - but your reputation will not suffer).

If you're asking for specific advice/implementation for problems that only affect your workplace - or asking for any kind of drawn out discussion - you're asking for work, which should happen through a consultant.

I feel that distinction is generally quite common-sense though, and doesn't need to much thought. If you'd be willing to reply to somebody else with what you're asking - then it's generally fine.